# read.fst() crashes R : workaround needed to detect corrupted file before read.fst()

Tags: r, data.table, fst

This is an issue already opened on fstpackage's [github](https://github.com/fstpackage/fst/issues/271#issue-1438248998), but it seems the package author is no longer actively maintaining it.

Meanwhile, I need a workaround to this crash problem, which is repeatable and occurs regularly but on a small subset of my files. I am trying to find a method to detect a corrupted `.fst` file, without actually reading it because the crash stops all the further processing of my script.

Here is a sample [corrupted fst file](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1hYJLAcqct_5JxTNNXN1c-qKH9bWFhgmO/view?usp=sharing) that you can download and try to open it using `fst::read.fst()`.
Your R session is likely to crash.
If your R session does not crash and you just get an error, then you are lucky (I have tried on an Ubuntu R server as well as on Mac OS with latest R 4.2 and everytime the R session crashes). It may not crash in specific situations, but the question still remains. (For details of the error message please see the github issue link above.)

I want some way to detect if a file is **clean** or **corrupted** *before* running `read.fst()`.

And yes, I have tried `tryCatch()` but the crash still occurs.

Perhaps scanning the header of the raw data of the file in octal / raw mode may be helpful in detecting unexpected characters like null characters that are causing the crash. But I leave it to you the expert to find a way.

**UPDATE**
Waldi has detected that surprisingly, column wise read.fst() does not crash. However, there are a few problems in this approach.

1. The column data is corrupted. The file I tested has last 2 (of 4 cols) corrupted. Outputs as follows:

```
> fst::read.fst("corrupted.fst",columns = c("termid","ts","rv","av"),from = 1,to = 10)
       termid                  ts            rv            av
1  1204011660                <NA> 4.646816e-310 4.646816e-310
2  1204011660 2022-07-21 07:52:43 4.646816e-310 4.646816e-310
3  1204011660 2022-08-18 16:37:19 4.646816e-310 4.646816e-310
4  1204011660 2022-08-18 16:37:20 4.646835e-310 4.646835e-310
5  1204011660 2022-08-18 16:37:50 4.646817e-310 4.646817e-310
6  1204011660 2022-08-18 16:38:13 4.646817e-310 4.646817e-310
7  1204011660 2022-08-18 16:38:43 4.646817e-310 4.646817e-310
8  1204011660 2022-08-18 16:39:13 4.646817e-310 4.646817e-310
9  1204011660 2022-08-18 16:39:15 4.646819e-310 4.646819e-310
10 1204011660 2022-08-18 16:39:45 4.646830e-310 4.646830e-310
```

2. The response time tanks, to 5 seconds for just outputting the first 10 rows.

```
> system.time(fst::read.fst("corrupted.fst",columns = c("termid","ts","rv","av"),from = 1,to = 10))
   user  system elapsed 
  2.069   3.874   5.940
```

3. Column-wise read crashes other corrupted files I have, so it is not a reliable method.

I am waiting for a faster & more reliable solution.

Comment: I just commented at GitHub. You may have better luck if you create a self-contained example crashing on data it wrote.

Comment: thanks, and added my comment on github https://github.com/fstpackage/fst/issues/271#issuecomment-1316466656

Comment: @sindri_baldur - I have already built considerable software creating small fst files for every asset under monitoring. Its an IOT system I have built.  What do you suggest, how much learning time would postgresSQL take?

Comment: thanks, i will give a last try to fst and then move to mysql in which I am more comfortable.

Comment: surprisingly; all columns of the corrupted file (`ts,rv,termid,av` ) can be read individually by using the `columns` argument, fi : `fst::read.fst('corrupted.fst',columns =c('termid'))`

Comment: Wow ! Let me try to test this @Waldi

Comment: Just tested, am updating the question with details.

Comment: Seems moving to mysql or mariadb is the best way forward.